# Content Editable UIWebView scrolls and overlaps over the button/images of uiview in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contenteditable

I have a view with few buttons and UIWebView which loaded content editable HTML.
In UIWebView i am inserting images/Canvas using both native and javascript functionality.

Since the WebView is editable whenever webview is clicked keyboard comes up. Now when we are inserting/editing a image/canvas keyboard should hide. So for that i am checking for tap event, getting the id of the element at that position and hiding the keyboard if that is a image/canvas using [webview endEditing:YES];.

Now the problem what i am facing is that if i add 2-3 images and then clicks on the webview, webview starts moving from its position and overlaps the button/images kept at the uiview. So the button are not visible and i am not able to perform the actions related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I was using some kind of animation when the keyboard was show/hidden. Once i removed that uiwebview doesn't moves.